# Alternatives to convert a array to a hash using same keys and values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-hash

I want to convert:

```
[:one, :two, :three]
```

to:

```
{one: :one, two: :two, three: :three}
```

So far I'm using this:

```
Hash[[:basic, :silver, :gold, :platinum].map { |e| [e, e] }]
```

But I would like to know if it's possible by some other way?

This is to use in a Rails `enum` definition in model, to save values as strings in db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer constructing hashes from scratch rather than constructing a temporary array (which consumes memory) and converting it to a hash.

```
[:one, :two, :three].each_with_object({}) { |e,h| h[e]=e }
  #=> {:one=>:one, :two=>:two, :three=>:three}
```

Comment: totally agree with creating hash from scratch, I usually resort to `each_with_object` in such cases, but `a.zip(a).to_h` is so much less typing :D

Answer (score 6):

[Array#`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
a = [:one, :two, :three]
a.zip(a).to_h
#=> {:one=>:one, :two=>:two, :three=>:three}
```

[Array#`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose):

```
[a, a].transpose.to_h
#=> {:one=>:one, :two=>:two, :three=>:three}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby on Rails 6+ it is possible to use [`Enumerable#index_with`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_with)

If combine it with [`Object#itself`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Object.html#method-i-itself), it will look such way:

```rb
%i[one two three].index_with(&:itself)

# => {:one=>:one, :two=>:two, :three=>:three}
```

And yes, it is convenient to use `enum` to declare strings stored in the database with hash such way

```rb
enum my_attribute: MY_ARRAY.index_with(&:itself)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way with [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
>> [:one, :two, :three].map { |x| [x,x] }.to_h
=> {:one=>:one, :two=>:two, :three=>:three}
```